# How to launch a Coroutine in an Fragment onStop() method in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am working on an Android application where my use-case demands that I call an API method after user leaves a `Fragment`. Let's call this **ListFragment**.

Basically, the `Fragment` shows a list of items which should be marked as read if a user has seen them. To achieve this, when the user leaves this `Fragment`, I call an API method which marks these items as read. The user can move to multiple other activities from this `Fragment` and it is not feasible to cal the API for marking items as read in all those other activities. The only reasonable solution is to call the coroutine for marking as read in the `onPause` or `onStop` method of `Fragment`.

I am unable to decide which scope should be used here. `viewModelScope` does not work in this case. `GlobalScope` works here, but I have read enough articles that discourage its use. What should I do here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One question, Are you marking read when a user has seen just a list of items or user clicks on the item? 
Now if you want to mark as read when user has seen the list screen, Then you can call API on fragment start. And if you want to mark them as read when the user clicks on the item then call API on item click.